# SQLite work around for Loops and Variable to allow varying N number of INSERT statements in a Trigger Statement

Tags: sqlite, loops, variables, sql-insert

I have two tables

I have a LineUp table

| Fixture | Number_Sub | Complete |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| 2 | 3 | TRUE |

When I change `Complete` to `TRUE` for example on row 2 I want to use a Trigger to `INSERT` 3 lines in to table `Sub` ...

| Fixture |
| --- |
| 1 |

...with the corresponding fixture number - it would look like this.....

| Fixture |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

The number in LineUp.Number_Sub is variable.

I am using Sqlite on a Mac and I know I can't use variables or loops but I am new to SQL and don't know where to start.

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate the help.

Also any tips on better wording of question would be great as I am new to this forum.

Comment: Are `Number_Sub`'s values in a limited range?

Answer (score 1):

You need an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger for the table `LineUp`.
This trigger should, somehow, do a loop, from `1` to the value of `Number_Sub` and each time insert a row in the table `Sub`.
Unfortunately SQLite does not support loop constructs and the only way to simulate this behavior would be a recursive [`CTE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html).
Unfortunately (again) [SQLite does not allow `CTE`s inside a trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html#limitations_and_caveats).

A workaround, is to create a table, say `Numbers`, with 1 column `number` and rows with values `1-100` (or the max value that can be stored in `Number_Sub`):

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers AS
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 1 AS number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT number + 1 FROM cte WHERE number < 100
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Now, you can create the trigger, which will insert into `Sub` as many rows as the value of `Number_Sub`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_LineUp_upd AFTER UPDATE OF Complete ON LineUp
WHEN NEW.Complete = 'TRUE'
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Sub(Fixture)
  SELECT NEW.Fixture
  FROM Numbers
  WHERE number <= NEW.Number_Sub;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=519b5de5f9cb5c5e3a5d78a2bb9d9d59).

I assumed that the value `TRUE` in the column `Complete` of the table `LineUp` is a string.
If it is a Boolean (Integer) value, then change `WHEN NEW.Complete = 'TRUE'` to `WHEN NEW.Complete`.